# Set SSRS report variable from code

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I building an SSIS report, and displaying it via a ReportViewer asp control. I already know how to pass parameters via code:

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

How can I do the same for the report's variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible.

Note that variables aren't meant for input, they are meant for [something else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255208.aspx):

> When you have a complex calculation that is used more than once in expressions in a report, you might want to create a variable.

Of course, you can base that calculation on input parameters.

If you find the need to set a value for a *variable* when viewing a report, you probably in fact need a *parameter*. Perhaps you're experiencing the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: In my report, I have place holders for the column names. I want the language of the column name to change dynamically - when the report loads I pass in a set of text strings for the column names. I can achieve that with parameters, but it looks like a workaround, as if parameters where not made for that use. For example, I need to set them to Hidden (Of course, because they aren't even related to data filtering).

Comment: Parameters aren't well suited for localization, but neither are variables. Running your report in the correct locale, using the [User!Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281090(v=sql.100).aspx) global, or passing a single `culuture` parameter is probably a better idea. Either way, the answer to your original question remains the same: passing values for variables isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is Possible

Refer the below link

[Modifying report variables in Reporting service 2008 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2012/02/03/modifying-report-variables-in-reporting-service-2008-r2.aspx)